# Why can't men sail in the waters of the Ekkaia?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium

Numenorean men sailed out into the outer sea but they sunk and drowned instantly.

Why is this? Is it because those waters are magical and enchanted to contain the beings of Middle-earth inside the world or because it's not a place Men are allowed to go?

Ekkaia is the outer sea beyond Valinor and the Land of the Sun

Comment: Planning your next extra-endoterrestrial foray and wanting to raise your chances of success beforehand, eh?

Answer (score 7):

### Because only ships blessed by Ulmo can

This is a holdover from *The Book of Lost Tales*, Tolkien's very first draft (emphasis mine):

> Beyond Valinor I have never seen or heard, save that of a surety there are the dark waters of the Outer Seas, that have no tides, and they are very cool and thin, that **no boat can sail upon their bosom or fish swim within their depths, save the enchanted fish of Ulmo and his magic car**.
>
> So here Ulmo says that neither fish nor boat will swim in its waters 'to whom I have not spoken the great word that Iluvatar said to me and bound them with the spell'.
>
> <sup>*History of Middle-earth* I *The Book of Lost Tales, Part 1* Chapter IX: "The Hiding of Valinor"</sup>

Only certain, magical ships are able to navigate the Outer Seas, and the ships of Númenor don't make the cut.

The reason for this quirk of creation is never elaborated on; chalk it up to the ineffable will of Eru.

Comment: I'd love to see Ulmo driving his car across the Outer Sea. But Jesusy, innit?

Comment: But didn't the Numenoreans manage to sail there after all and as a punishment Numenor was destroyed and sunk? Or was this with the help of Sauron who lived in Numenor at this time fueled the desire to go there.

Comment: @Thomas Wrong sea. In the First and Second Ages, there's an actual, navigable (mostly) sea separating Middle-earth and Aman, and Ekkaia surrounds both; after the Second Age is when that changed

Comment: What does the term "magic car" mean? That's very strange.

Comment: @maguirenumber6 In modern language, we would say something like "cart" or "chariot"; consider [definitions 4, 5, and 6](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/car?s=t)